# What is the purpose of the R-divider in a String DAC?

Tags: resistors, voltage-divider, dac

I'm not sure if this is duplicate but a String DAC model is always shown as follows:

[image]

And R-divider is equal to the sum of the DAC resistors below it. And to compensate that a gain of 2 is used at the opmap.

But why not omitting the R-divider completely and use gain of 1? Would that yield the same result? What is the purpose of the R-divider in such String DAC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Appears a "string DAC" uses a one-of-N decoder and only one switch is 'on' at a time.

One good reason to use a Rdivider and x2 is that the op-amp inputs then need not handle common mode voltage equal to the supply. That makes the op-amp less expensive to build and better (more linear) performance since you don't need to have two front end transistor pairs and transition between them (where Vos tends to vary, affecting linearity and perhaps even monotonicity).

Okay, the [TI web page](https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/analogwire/posts/dac-essentials-string-theory#:%7E:text=In%20its%20simplest%20form%2C%20the,switched%20to%20the%20output%20buffer.) where the OP apparently clipped the image does provide the same explanation as I have.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Regarding "the op-amp inputs then need not handle common mode voltage equal to the supply." Isnt CM voltage the average of inverting and non-inverting inputs? Without  Rdivider could you show why CM voltage could be equal to Vcc?

Comment: If the top switch is closed, and Rdivider == 0, and G=1 (voltage follower) then both op-amp inputs need to be at Vcc for balance.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I should have thought that.

Answer (score 0):

The R_divider is necessary so that when all the switches are ON, Vref will not be shorted to GND.

I may have misunderstood the configuration in question, which seems to be a fully decoded "string DAC" where all resistors are equal. But that is not very practical for higher resolution DACs, as it requires 2^n resistors and switches for a n-bit DAC.

Here are some references for various DAC configurations. The first one is for a string DAC, but the R_divider seems to have the same value as those in the string.

https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-014.pdf

https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-015.pdf

https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-016.pdf

OK, I found that configuration here, which also contains the reasoning for the R_divider:

https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/analogwire/posts/dac-essentials-string-theory

And part 2 which discusses the R-2R and MDAC architectures:

https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/analogwire/posts/dac-essentials-the-resistor-ladder

Comment: You mean when the bottom switch is ON? All the switches cannot be ON at the same time(?) One switch per code isnt it?

Comment: I was thinking about a binary weighted DAC, which uses an R/2R network. I could not find the exact configuration that you show, which is a fully decoded DAC with all (2^n) resistors equal and only one switch at a time. The string DAC I found has R_divider the same value as each of the string resistors. Can you add a link to the configuration you show in your question?

Comment: If the code was 11111 (or 0000) all the switches would be on.